# handling null values in linq to sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

i have to handle exception in my query when assigning values in view model ie i have set the values in view model when any value is null it is not showing other fields of my table showing error object reference error how to handle this error in my query 
my code is as follows-

```
 var query = (from results in db.Resumes
                         where results.ResumeID == ResumeID && results.User.UserID == uid

                         select results).ToList().Select(results=>new ResumewizardPreviewmodel
                         {
                             Resumetitle = results.ResumeTitle??"",
                             DesiredJob = results.DesiredJob??"",
                             Objective = results.Objective??"",
                             DesiredCompany = results.DesiredCompany??"",
                                  DesiredSalary = results.DesiredSalary.ToString(), 
                             Salarytype = results.SalaryType,
                             additionalinfo = results.AdditionalInfo,
                             res_url = results.Res_URL,
                             visa = results.Visa.ToString()??"0",
                             TelecommuteType = results.TelecommuteType.Description,
                             RelocationType = results.RelocationType.Description,
                             isactive = results.IsActive,
                             isConfidential = results.isConfidential




                         }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to convert one entity to another.

Here is an [example](http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/2011/03/07/automapper-mapping-objects-part-1-of-7-nullsubsitution/) of converting collections and null value substitution.

Comment: when any field is null how will it assign results and make object of viewmodel for which i have to handle null exception so how can i do that

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper it handles them automatically.

Comment: no it doesnt because when desiredcompany field is null it is giving object reference error i have checked

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper did you use AutoMapper?

Comment: solved the problem it is giving error on casting conversion so i have removed it from viewmodel and assign it in variable after checking null value